# Using Google Analytics filter to get a specific search

Tags: google-analytics

So I'm trying to get a site to have a profile with only one group being looked at.

I tried putting in a filter that only included traffic the the subdirectories containing /browse.php?CISOROOT=/wss but that removed everything from the results.

When I search the top content for browse.php I can find the page, but when I add the ?CISOROOT part on I get no results.  How can I get these to show up??

Answer (score 0):

I changed the filter to just include /wss and it works fine now.